# Clearing the Tkinter window (NOT closing it) after a button click

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently playing around with tkinter for a school project. I have a basic welcome screen set up, but after i hit the "start" button I want the screen to clear so I can make another "page."

My current code is this:

```
# IMPORTS #
import tkinter as tk
# ------- #

# Define Window #
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Bioinformatics Showcase")
window.geometry("600x400")
# ------------- #

# Clear screen function #
def clearScreen(object):
    screenItem = object.grid_slaves()
    for i in screenItem:
        i.destroy()
# --------------------- #

# Event functions #
def startEvent(event):
    clearScreen(window)
# ------- #

# Create Welcome Page #
welcomeLabel = tk.Label(text="Welcome, User! :3")
welcomeLabel.place(relx = .5, rely = .1, anchor = "center")
    # Make start button
startButton = tk.Button(window, text = "Click here to start")
startButton.place(relx = .5, rely = .5, anchor = "center")
    # Bind button to start event
startButton.bind("<Button-1>", startEvent) # <Button-1> is the mouse left click
# ------------------- #

# Main loop keeps window open until user closes it #
window.mainloop()
```

For some reason, when I press the "Click here to start" button, nothing happens. By clearing the screen, I mean I want welcomeLabel and startButton to disappear from the GUI screen; I want it to look like if my code was only the following:

```
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Bioinformatics Showcase")
window.geometry("600x400")

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a frame, placing all element in that frame, and destroying that frame will help you to solve your problem

Here's the basic example:

```
frame=tk.Frame(window)
frame.pack()

button = tk.Button(frame, text = "Destroy All")
button.pack()

button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x: frame.destroy())
```

This will destroy all elements which are in frame.

Comment: But I actually recommend, to create new window...  Over doing this, if possible...

Answer (score 0):

You have used `.place()` to put widgets into `window`, so you need to use `.place_slaves()` instead of `.grid_slaves()` to get the list of widgets:

```
def clearScreen(obj):
    screenItem = obj.place_slaves()
    for i in screenItem:
        i.destroy()
```

Or you can use `.winfo_children()`:

```py
def clearScreen(obj):
    screenItem = obj.winfo_children()
    for i in screenItem:
        i.destroy()
```

Note that it is not recommended to use `object` as variable name because it is a reserved word in Python.